# Datetime anomaly with abreviated months

Tags: python

I cannot fathom what is going in the following example

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Aug 10", "%b %y")
datetime.datetime(2010, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

Makes sense %b is abreviated month name and %y is year so August 2010 corresponds to `datetime(2010, 8, 1, 0, 0)`

However if i change %y to %m, where %m is day of the month it gets weird

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("Aug 10", "%b %m")
datetime.datetime(1900, 10, 1, 0, 0)
```

All of a sudden it refuses to recognize "Aug"

Comment: You're passing ambiguous value to it, so it takes the last value. And %d is used for day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code does not work is very simple: `%m` is not the **day of month**, but the **number** of month. Now the month first matches Aug, then 10, and that is what you get. Try `%d` instead for day of month.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('Aug 10', '%b %d')
datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 10, 0, 0)
```

See also [8.1.7. strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)